# Autolispのコマンドから図面を開きたい

Tags: ijcad, lisp

IJCAD 2023 に AutoCAD から Autolisp で開発したツールの移行を行っています。

コマンドから図面を開く操作を行っているlspファイルを使用しているのですが、command 関数を使用して図面を開こうとすると、図面を開くことが出来ません。

現象を再現するには、CAD が起動した状態で、テキストウインドウに以下のコードを入力します。

```
(command "open")
```

実行するとnilが返ってきて、図面を開くことができません。

SDI (システム変数)は0でも1でも結果は同じでした。

Autolisp で定義したコマンドから図面を開く動作を行うには何か別の方法があるでしょうか？

以上になります。
よろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Autolisp で定義したコマンドから図面を開く動作を行うには何か別の方法があるでしょうか？

図面を開く動作を行う場合、AutoCADにおいても(command "open")では開くことができなくて、
(command "fileopen" <図面のパス>)とすると目的の図面を開く動作ができると思います。

ただしIJCADだとFILEOPENコマンドが実装されていないようなので
IJCADでは目的の動作はできないと考えられます。